# How to detect mouse pointer in scroll bar on Mouseleave event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseleave

I have to show an alert while the mouse leaves the window, I tried with mouseleave event, but the alert is showing when i move the pointer to the scrollbar  also. I have to show the alert when the mouse reaches outside the window (while i try to navigate to other tabs) but not on scrollbars.

Kindly help me to solve the issue

Comment: You could use the as Page Visibility API http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/ described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Comment: It work. When mouse move to out of window(bookmark-bar, addressbar, ect) alert shown.